# Selecting power resistor

Tags: power, resistors, heatsink

I want to build a thermostat and I'm not sure what power resistor to choose. The thermostat will be build inside a broken microwave oven. The resistors will be connected to 230V AC and they will be controlled by an arduino pro mini for AC PWM using a triac + other components.

I'm thinking to go for 2 or 3, 50W 1.5k ohms power resistors connected in paralel.This is how they look: https://www.tme.eu/en/details/ax50wr-1k5/50w-resistors/te-connectivity/1-1625984-9/

According to my calculations, I will have:

I = 230/1500 =  0.153A

P = I x V = 35.19W

So 35.19W is ok, given that the resistor maximum power is 50w. But in the data sheet is mentioned that without a heatsink the maximum power drops to 20W.
So I don't know how the metal plate of the microwave oven would compare to a heatsink. It would be safe to use these resistors?

I want to make fermented yogurt from bacteria. So I need a temperature between 40-45C so that the bacteria wont die. Also, in the instructions, it says that in order to make ticker yogurt, it would help to keep the milk at 70C for 30 mins. That's why I'm doing it. But in the future, I might use it for other things as well.

Comment: You can calculate it, but thermal model of oven will be very complex. IMHO, instead of earning a PhD degree in thermodynamics just mount resistors using some thermal grease and make test.

Comment: Yeah, I think that most likely they would work. When I will receive them I will test and see. I asked because I didnt't wanted to order the wrong resistors.

Comment: What you're doing is a bit iffy, since you're making no effort to keep the resistors cool - rather, you _want_ them (and the oven) to get hot. However, microwave ovens aren't well-insulated, so you may be all right. Of course, you may not get the oven very hot, too, but you haven't mentioned your target temperature - which you should have done to begin with.

Comment: For now, the temperature I want is 45C, but in the future I might want 70-80C. But the metal plate wont act kinda like a heatsink? It will dissipate some heat, although not as efficient.

Comment: There could be a significant shock hazard with this design. You need to give careful consideration to grounding strategy. Any exposed conductive surface which could possibly come into contact with line voltage must be well grounded with a low-impedance ground connection.

Comment: I recommend that you use high temperature insulation for all wiring inside the microwave oven. For example silicone insulation as opposed to PVC or similar.

Comment: @mkeith I will keep the ground design of the oven. I will also measure the temperature on where the arduino will be, it shouldn't be too hot, there's a distance between where the resistors are and the arduino. Also, if it will be too hot, I will change the max temp for safety.

Comment: Can you do basic Thermodynamic calculations for thermal resistance/ conductance and energy / kgm for temp slew rate? Then you know what power you need.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist If I knew, I wouldn't ask for help.

Comment: Ok why then are you doing this?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I want to make fermented yogurt from bacteria. So I need a temperature between 40-45C so that the bacteria wont die. Also, in the instructions, it says that in order to make ticker yogurt, it would help to keep the milk at 70C for 30 mins. That's why I'm doing it. But in the future, I might use it for other things as well.

Comment: The oven with a circulating fan would be better. The milk is being repasteurized while the yogurt needs active temperature without killing it with a cloth cover.

Comment: A good way to make yogurt is to warm the milk carefully in a pot, and then put it in a cooler that has several inches of warmwater at the bottom of it. The water in the cooler should be near the high side of your desired temperature range. If desired (not really needed) you can add a bit more hot water to the cooler after a few hours.

Comment: Just so you understand, if you touch the electrical terminals of the resistors when they are energized, you will possibly receive a fatal shock.

Comment: @mkeith I understand the risk. It was even more dangerous when the microwave oven worked because of the much higher voltage from the transformer. I wont touch the terminals of the resistors. I will use M3 screws to attach them to the bottom of the oven metalic plate. I know of the multiple ways in which i can make yogurt, but if I make it often, it will be boring to warm water every time. I want to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Some people also use sous vide circulators to make yogurt. The microwave should already have a micro-switch on the door to de-energize the microwave heating element when someone opens the door. Maybe you can use that same feature to de-energize your heating elements. I think it is well worth it. Being careful works for things you only do once in a while. But not for things you do regularly. Also, someone else may open it at some point.

Comment: Or do you mean the resistors won't even be in the main compartment? You plan to attach them below the floor of the heating area? If so, then yeah. That is already pretty safe. If you do that, you should buy different resistors, though. Buy the puck style ones that transfer almost all their heat through the heatsink.

Comment: Example: https://www.ohmite.com/assets/docs/res_tgh.pdf?r=false

Comment: @mkeith Yes, they will be below the floor of the heating compartment, where it used to be the motor that turns the microwave oven plate. So only a little bit of screws will be in the heating compartment. The resistors you recommended werent in stock at my eshop. And also they seem to be available from 100W+, and not from 50W. Would the ones that I intended to use in the first place be really bad?

Comment: Not really. It is just that you are trying to heat up the main chamber. So the more heat they transfer to the plate the better. The resistors you are looking at have more exposed area. Let's say they transfer 50% of heat to the bottom chamber, and 50% to the plate. The other ones transfer 80% to the plate and 20% to the bottom chamber. Numbers are made up to illustrate what I THINK will happen. It should work either way, unless something overheats that shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best forms of power resistor to use for this sort of '10s of watts to modest temperatures' mains heating application is a filament lightbulb.

Wire a bulb-holder inside the space to be heated, and arrange a fan to circulate air in there. Obviously these have to be rated for your target temperature, but you get types for intended for ovens.

Consider the advantages. They're already designed for mains, and to get hot. They're self-indicating. They're inexpensive and available. The bulb holder is already insulated to mains standards from its mounting. And there's a danger of broken glass, which encourages you to be careful.

Comment: Some incubators for chicken eggs rely on incandescent bulbs for heat. Seems to work well.

Comment: I tried my circuit using a bulb. I used my arduino with a light dimmer. So I used a 100W incandescent bulb. The yogurt was fine. But I tested it in my big, normal, gas oven. As you know, in the microwave oven the space is more limited, so the risk of breaking the bulb is serious. But it could be a solution if I plan it carefully using smaller bulbs designed for oven. Would it matter if I put the bulb up, instead of down? If it is up the risk of breaking is lower. But it would affect the temerature distribution. The fan should always be powered? Or briefly switched on for a period of time?

Comment: I would not think you would need a fan.

Comment: @Novak it depends how uniform you want the temperature. With a fan running all the time, it will be more uniform. It might be uniform enough for your purposes without a fan, try it and see, it's obviously simpler without.